# Spherical platykurtic random cloud

Tags: distributions, random-variable, kurtosis, multivariate-analysis

I'd like to generate a multivariate continuous data which is **globular** cloud, like multivariate standard normal data is, but which is more **platykurtic** than normal data.

There are many ways to get platykurtic data (e.g. from beta distribution) but the more platykurtic they are the more they are rectangular shape in multivariate space. But I want globular, hyperspherical random data. Unimodal data. Preferably from not bounded distribution, if possible. And with an option to vary the amount of flat kurtosis.

**Can you suggest** a distribution or a trick to generate?

P.S. Saying "hyperspherical" I mean "any dimensionality" (not "high dimensionality"). That is, I imply 2D case to be just particular case; I'm interested in it as well.

Comment: "Platykurtic" could mean many things for multivariate data. Are you perhaps referring to just the *marginal* distributions?  If so, would it matter if they became multimodal?

Comment: No. Bell-shaped, unimodal like normal, only with more flat middle and light tails, than normal. Density function should be identical in all space directions from the centroid, again like with i.i.d. multivariate normal. So, I'm not speaking of just marginal distributions. (One way would be to generate each value from any univariate, 0-symmetric, platykurtic distribution I might like, and than to add a random angular swing to it in multidimensional space. But I would be happy to collect advices first.)

Comment: For a spherically symmetric distribution you *are* speaking of just the marginals since they are all the same.  When you rotate a distribution as you describe, note that the marginal will not be the same as the radial distribution.  For instance, the radial distribution for the multivariate Normal is Gamma.  Nevertheless, that approach of prescribing the distribution in spherical coordinates will work when you choose a suitable radial distribution to begin with--but you don't want it to have a mode at zero.

Comment: I'm really thankful for you comment. I thought it might be a good idea to expand it and make **an answer**. In particular, can you point me to where I could learn more about a connection between the marginal distribution and the corresponding radial distribution, in a multivariate spherically symmetric distribution such as normal? Also, I didn't understand your words `you don't want it to have a mode at zero`.

Comment: More clarification is needed to answer your question. I get the sense from your responses below that you are specifically interested in identifying a function which, when applied to normally-distributed data, yields platykurtotic data. This is an interesting question, but I'm wondering if you have considered (or ruled out) more direct ways, such as using the [inverse transformation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) using uniformly distributed data and the quantile function of a platykurtotic random variable.

Comment: An additional strategy would be to use [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) with the pdf of a platykurtotic distribution. An appropriately parametrized [Pearson type VII distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_distribution#The_Pearson_type_VII_distribution) could do the trick.

Comment: One other question about your question. When you say you are interested in multivariate distributions, is it sufficient to generate $p$ independent platykurtotic variables? Or do you want/need to construct dependencies between the variables? If independent variables are acceptable, then this question boils down to finding methods for generating univariate platykurtotic data, right?

Comment: @ahfoss, No correlations. I need i.i.d. platykurtic (with the degree of flatness that I can vary from normal towards more flat/tail-light) unimodal spherical (2D,3D,...manyD) data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this is obviously related to my previous answer, I think it's different enough to be considered separately. Given a point in an $n$-dimensional cloud of iid standard normals, shrink it radially a chosen proportion of the way to the corresponding fractile of a uniform distribution in the unit-radius $n$-ball.

For iid standard normals in $n$ dimensions, the distance from the origin has a $\chi_n$ distribution. Let $F_n(d)$ denote its cdf. For a uniform distribution in the unit-radius $n$-ball, the cdf of the distance from the origin is $d^n$, and the inverse cdf is $p^{1/n}$. So multiply each point's coordinate vector by $1 + \alpha(F_n(d)^{1/n}/d - 1)$, where $\alpha$ is the chosen proportion and $d$ is the observed distance of the point from the origin.

EDIT -- A minor improvement, that makes the results easier to interpret: Scale the ball so that the mean square distance of the points from the origin is the same as the normal, $n$. The corresponding multiplier on the vector of normals is $1 + \alpha\,(F_n(d)^{1/n}\sqrt{n+2}\,/d - 1)$.

I have no proof that the marginal distribution is unimodal, but I have looked at histograms of marginal distributions with $\alpha = 0, .05, \ldots, 1$ for $n = 1, \ldots, 10$, and they all look as they should, varying smoothly from $\mathrm{N}(0,1)$ to a shifted and scaled $\mathrm{Beta}(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{n+1}{2})$. For $n = 2$ I have also looked at scatter plots with the same set of $\alpha$-values, and they too look as they should, with no "bald spot" in the middle.

Here is Mathematica code whose results are organized to facilitate exploring the effect of $\alpha$.

```
{m, n} = { sample size, # of dimensions };
z = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[], {m, n}];
y = z * With[{dd = Total[z^2, {2}]},
    CDF[ChiSquareDistribution[n], dd]^(1/n) * Sqrt[(n + 2)/dd]];
```

Then `x = alpha*y + (1-alpha)*z` will be a matrix that varies smoothly with `alpha` between iid normal (`alpha = 0`; pure `z`) and a uniform n-ball (`alpha = 1`; pure `y`). Here are scatter plots of 5000 points in 2 dimensions for `alpha = {0, .25, .50, .75, 1}`.

[image]

Comment: This answer suffers from the same deficiency as your previous one: it is speculative because it does not demonstrate that the resulting marginal distribution will be unimodal.

Comment: Re the edits: Thank you for gathering and sharing evidence that your proposal will work as intended (+1).

Comment: Ray, I liked your this solution a lot and I feel satisfied. In addition to your testing marginal distributions, I tested the resulting radial distribution (by that term, I mean the distribution along the randomly spinning beam from the origin of the cloud) for 2D, 3d, 4D data. With `alpha=1`, that distribution was indeed uniform. I found no bimodality for `alpha` between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

For a cloud of i.i.d. standard normals, try shrinking the points toward the origin logarithmically. That is, multiply the coordinates of each point by $\log(1+\alpha\, d)/(\alpha\, d)$, where $d$ is the distance of the point from the origin, and $\alpha$ controls the amount of shrinkage, with larger values shrinking more.

Comment: That looks like an easy and neat solution. I expect that this or similar approach - to draw in a tail proportionally to the deviation from the origin - may suit me. One question: Why are you suggesting specifically logarithming? Do you thing square root, for example, is worse?

Comment: No special reason. I also considered multiplying by $\mathrm{arcsinh}(\alpha\,d)/(\alpha\,d)$, but something based on the square (or some other) root might do just as well.

Comment: The square root (that is, $\sqrt{d}/d$) will not work: it produces a bimodal marginal distribution.  Thus there *are* special reasons to use the logarithm.

Comment: I should add that I required the multiplier to approach $1$ as $d$ approaches $0$.

Comment: Ray, the problem with your formula is that the higher is alpha the more bimodal (I mean, ring-like) the result is. Take, for example, bivariate st. normal data and apply the transformation with alpha=3. The centre of the cloud is clearly gone bald. Even with alpha=1 there are signs of "baldness".

Comment: @ttnphns That's not correct.  You may be describing the full 3D distribution.  The marginals in Ray's construction are fine.  Nevertheless, there's an important point to your comment (and to my earlier one): this answer--which is no more than an unsupported claim--really needs some justification and a clearer indication of which rescaling approaches will produce a unimodal distribution.

Comment: Ray, @whuber, please see the pictures that I added temporarily to the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I mentioned *three* dimensions because you used "hyperspherical" in the question, suggesting little or no interest in one or two dimensions.  In both one and two dimensions the marginal is indeed bimodal.  In higher dimensions you won't have problems with Ray's formula.  Once again it is clear that this answer really needs some analysis to show (a) that it can work and (b) under which circumstances it does work.

Comment: @whuber, 1) I'm intrigued with your notion that in 3+ dimensions there will be no problem. Did you mean to say the phenomenon that the central region becomes less dense than some more peripheral envelope will disappear? Why it should? 2) My question takes interest in any dimensionality, includind 2D and even 1D.

Comment: It's a property of higher dimensions: for sufficiently large $d$, there is virtually no hypervolume in the interior of the unit sphere compared to a tiny shell just outside the sphere, so what goes on near the origin will make less of a contribution to the marginals as the dimension increases. That's precisely why the mode of a Gamma distribution (aka $\chi^2$) shifts to larger values as the degrees of freedom (aka $d$) increase.

Comment: @whuber, I see. You must be referring to one aspect of what they call "Curse of dimensionality". However, as I've said, low dimensional cases such as 2D or 3D bother me too, and so the situation when the distribution becomes evacuated in the middle is intolerable.

Comment: So in terms of a parameter such as $\alpha$ in the transformations I suggested, where zero gives no pull-in and increasing values give increasing pull-in, what do you want the limiting distribution to be as $\alpha \rightarrow \infty$ -- uniform over the interior of a ball?

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I won't object to semicircular distribution as the limiting, either. Actually I have no request that the distribution be of a well-known type. The request is that neither marginal nor radial distribution is ever become bimodal.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into the generalized normal distribution, a generalization of the normal distribution that introduces a parameter that controls the kurtosis. It includes as special cases the laplace, normal, and uniform distributions. There appears to be a citation on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution) that discusses the multivariate generalized normal distribution. Just a note of caution -- there is at least one other distribution called the "generalized normal" distribution; the alternate one I am thinking of involves parametric control of skewness, not kurtosis, so make sure you are reading about the "correct" generalized normal distribution!

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've already known about that possibility. But there remains practical question about how to easily generate that sort of data (i.e without some advanced software). Let me put a specific question in front of you. You have 3-variate standard normal data (or function generating it). Can you suggest a way to transform it into generalized normal platykurtic data?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some context here. Specifically, what do you mean by "easily generate." You can generate data which (I think) satisfies your criteria with a one-liner in R after installing the pgnorm package: pgnorm::rpgnorm(n=1000,p=4). Is part of your requirement that you cannot use R? I'm also confused about why you need to start with multivariate normal data, as opposed to just generating platykurtotic data directly.

Comment: I'm not R user, I'm SPSS user. As far as I remember SPSS has no random number functions for generalized normal distributions. So, if to follow your interesting suggestion, I'll have to code such generative function myself. If you know the algorithm please forward me to it. I don't insist to start with multivariate normal, I just feel it might be a convenient way: please remember that I need strictly _spherical_ cloud (multivariate uniform - an utmost platykurtic generalized normal - isn't spherical!)

Comment: Note that when $2 < p < \infty$ the generalized normal distribution is platykurtotic, and has infinite tails. The uniform distribution only arises in the limiting case when $p \rightarrow \infty$. There are five methods for generating generalized normal but I think they are more complex than you are looking for. They are described in this paper: S. Kalke and W.-D. Richter."Simulation of the p-generalized Gaussian distribution." Journal of Statistical Computation and Simulation.

Answer (score 2):

The Johnson $S_U$ distribution (see citation below) has infinite tails and can be platykurtotic based on your parameter choices. It is easily generated from normally distributed data as follows:

$$ Z = \gamma + \delta \; \text{sinh}^{-1} \left(\frac{X-\xi}{\lambda} \right) $$

where $X \sim N(0,1)$. You probably just want to set $\gamma=\xi=0$ and $\lambda=1$. The parameter $\delta$ controls kurtosis, with higher values resulting in smaller kurtosis.

Here is a contour plot (with R code) showing the bivariate density of independent $S_U$ variables:

```
library(SuppDists)

parms = list(gamma=0,delta=2,xi=0,lambda=2,type='SU')
coords = seq(-3,3,0.01)
zz = outer(
    X=coords,Y=coords,
    FUN=function(x,y) c(dJohnson(x,parms)*dJohnson(y,parms))
)
contour(coords,coords,zz)
```

[image: Bivariate Density of Independent Johnson's $S_U$ Variables]

The shape of the distribution is a bit more clear if we look at univariate densities:

curve(dJohnson(x,parms),from=-3,to=3)

[image: Univariate Density of Johnson's $S_U$]

Note that $\xi$ is the location parameter, meaning that it shifts the distribution left and right leaving variance, skewness, and kurtosis unchanged. $\lambda$ is the scale parameter, meaning that it changes the variance but leaves mean, skewness, and kurtosis unchanged. $\gamma$ changes skewness and $\delta$ changes kurtosis, but they affect lower moments as well.

For example, we can calculate theoretical variance and kurtosis in R when $\gamma=0,\xi=0,\delta=1,\lambda=1$:

```
lam1 = sJohnson(list(gamma=0,delta=1,xi=0,lambda=1,type='SU'))
lam1$Variance
##[1] 3.194528
lam1$Kurtosis
##[1] 33.18813
```

Note that if we change $\lambda$ to 2 and hold the other parameters constant variance changes but kurtosis remains the same:

```
lam2 = sJohnson(list(gamma=0,delta=1,xi=0,lambda=2,type='SU'))
lam2$Variance
##[1] 12.77811
lam2$Kurtosis
##[1] 33.18813
```

Note that if we then change $\delta$ to 2 and hold the other parameters constant (keep $\lambda=2$), both variance and kurtosis change:

```
del2lam2 = sJohnson(list(gamma=0,delta=2,xi=0,lambda=2,type='SU'))
del2lam2$Variance
##[1] 1.297443
del2lam2$Kurtosis
##[1] 1.507862
```

Citation: Johnson NL (1949). Systems of Frequency Curves Generated by Methods of Translation.  Biometrika 36(1/2), 149-176. See in particular equation 21.

Comment: I haven't heard of Johnson's modification formulas. So thank you much. Your answer, however is mistaken and doesn't suit my needs so far. The mistake (probably a lapse) is that it is in fact lambda, not delta, parameter which regulate flatness. And the approach can't suit because the modification doesn't preserve multivariate _sphericity_. As Ray Koopman commented to his answer, `arsinh()` might be used perhaps, but that should take _d_ (not _X_) as argument.

Comment: Take a look at the paper I cited and you'll see that my formula is correct, specifically with regard to $X$ being the appropriate argument. If by multivariate sphericity you mean spherical contour lines of the multivariate density, Johnson's $S_U$ distribution satisfies this. I'll post a few densities in my answer as proof. I'm also editing my post to show the appropriate way to parametrize changes in kurtosis.

Comment: Actually, after adding moment calculations and density plots to my answer above, I've tested the R functions in question and the output seems questionable, specifically with regard to whether $\lambda$ or $\delta$ controls kurtosis. In calls to sJohnson (moment calculations), delta controls kurtosis, but in calls to dJohnson (density function), it appears that lambda controls kurtosis... this is worth a separate cross validated thread. Until this is resolved, my answer above should be read with caution since it assumes the functions are correct.

Comment: Of course not delta, but lambda. Delta is about variance, it is obvious from the formula.

Comment: Hmm... I agree with you that it seems that $\delta$ should be the scale factor, but I'm hesitant to write off the authors of the SuppDists package so easily, let alone Johnson himself:

Comment: "It follows that the parameters $\gamma$ and $\delta$ determine the shape of the distribution of $x$, that $\lambda$ is a scale factor and $\xi$ a location factor. It follows also that attention should be concentrated on the relation between the values of $\gamma$ and $\delta$ and the distribution of $x$, since the parameters $\xi$ and $\lambda$ affect the distribution only in a simple manner." pp. 152, same citation as above.

Comment: @ttnphns There's something odd going on here, in a few days I might have some time to sit down and figure it out. If you (or anyone else) make any progress, please post your findings. The Johnson paper is available on JSTOR if you're interested; you can sign up for a free account and read it online.

Comment: When I knew from you about Johnson SU I immedialely looked in the internet and found 2 or 3 places citing the same formula as you gave but without describing the 4 parameters. I sat and quickly computed some examples. It appeared to me that lambda controls kurtosis: lambda of +infinity introduces no change to multivariate st. normal cloud; going down, lambda, makes data more platykurtic; lambda between 1 and 0 make normal data even bimodal.