# How to randomly shuffle tiny spheres inside a big sphere?

Tags: distributions, python, random-variable, poisson-distribution, algorithms

I have a list of spheres with some known characteristics (ids, radii, masses, and positions) with *ids*, *radii*, and *masses* being *1D arrays* with shape (511, ) and *positions* being *3D array* with shape (511, 3) inside some big spherical volume with known center, *(0, 0, 0)* and radius, *distance_max*.

```
hal_ids_data = np.array([19895, 19896, ..., 24249])                   
hal_radiuss_data = np.array([1.047, 1.078, ..., 3.263])                 
hal_masss_data = np.array([2.427e+06, 8.268e+06, ..., 8.954e+07]     
hal_positions_data = np.array([np.array([-33.78, 10.4, 33.83]), np.array([-33.61, 6.34, 35.64]), ..., np.array([-0.4014, 4.121, 33.05])])
```

I would like to randomly place these tiny spheres throughout the volume within the big sphere while keeping their individual characteristics intact meaning only their positions need to be shuffled *subject to two constraints shown below*.

```
for hal_id, hal_position, hal_radius, hal_mass in zip(hal_ids_data, hal_positions_data, hal_radiuss_data, hal_masss_data):

    # check if 1) any one of the small spheres are above some mass threshold AND 2) inside the big sphere
    if ((np.sqrt(pow(hal_position[0], 2)+pow(hal_position[1], 2)+pow(hal_position[2], 2)) < distance_max) and (log10(hal_mass)>=1e8)):

        # if so, then do the following stuff down here but to the shuffled populations of small spheres meeting the conditions above rather than to the original population
```

What is the fastest and shortest numerical algorithm to shuffle my small spheres *under the last `if statement` before doing some stuff on them*? (I do need my original population info though for later use so I cannot disregard it)

Comment: Do the little spheres need to be disjoint or can they overlap?

Comment: They can overlap. All I care is that their positions (centers) are distributed based on a uniform random distribution.

Comment: Aren you just asking, then, how to generate uniformly random locations within a given sphere?  One (good) method is given in the *question* at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85488.

Comment: Thank You, yes. this is what I want. Thank You,

Comment: See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481715/) for an ```R``` function that does this for you.

Comment: I am more interested in a 3D version of the problem where I can place my sphere in a uniformly distributed random position inside a bigger sphere. So, I think what whuber pointed out is the best option fo rme but I am trying to see why it still seems that we are biased by putting more points in the innermost region of the big sphere.

Comment: Thank You Ben, but I actually am not familiar much with R